# How to unset/destroy a level of JSONArray key

Tags: java, json, spring

I would like to know how to unset or destroy a level of JSON object.
Is this can be done using any Java Spring framework or could be define any custom functionality for this solution.
But require to retain the data inside array of inside of "txtFrameArr" as below.Example i have this result :

```
 [
  {
    "txtFrameArr": {
      "CEPDuplicateTextFrame1": [
        {
          "marked": 1,
          "id_elems": [
            {
              "PS": "1",
              "OS": "1",
              "LS": "999",
              "name": "MARKETING_CLAIM",
              "IS": "1",
              "id": "CE-MARKETING_CLAIM-1_999_1_1"
            }
          ],
          "mapCordinates": [
            {
              "top": 468.645102009805,
              "left": 1053.47265625,
              "width": 30.8357511971699,
              "height": 132.963461384805
            },
            {
              "top": 513.29412308266,
              "left": 1067.05751323149,
              "width": 91.1260246588899,
              "height": 233.24627152016
            }
          ],
          "duplicate": 1,
          "content": "baby-dry pants",
          "txtframe_name": "ceptxtduplicateTF1-threaded1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "txtFrameArr": {
      "CEPTextFrame2": [
        {
          "marked": 1,
          "id_elems": [
            {
              "PS": "1",
              "OS": "1",
              "LS": "2",
              "name": "NET_CONTENT_STATEMENT",
              "IS": "1",
              "id": "CE-NET_CONTENT_STATEMENT-1_2_1_1"
            }
          ],
          "mapCordinates": [
            {
              "top": 22.599609375,
              "left": 740.23886611805,
              "width": 22.9008135909007,
              "height": 33.8291015625
            },
            {
              "top": -6.76171875,
              "left": 744.522124684196,
              "width": 15.4768987533043,
              "height": 9.2734375
            },
            {
              "top": -14.33203125,
              "left": 740.448785213874,
              "width": 22.2500000017299,
              "height": 6.88811848711339
            }
          ],
          "duplicate": 0,
          "content": "4단계 9-14 kg",
          "txtframe_name": "ceptxtCE-NET_CONTENT_STATEMENT-1_2_1_1-threaded2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "txtFrameArr": {
      "CEPTextFrame3": [
        {
          "marked": 1,
          "id_elems": [
            {
              "PS": "1",
              "OS": "1",
              "LS": "2",
              "name": "USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS",
              "IS": "4",
              "id": "CE-USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS-4_2_1_1"
            }
          ],
          "mapCordinates": [
            {
              "top": 215.9384765625,
              "left": -639.0234375,
              "width": 29.1552734375,
              "height": 55.2314453125
            }
          ],
          "duplicate": 0,
          "content": "위로 당기며 입혀줍니다",
          "txtframe_name": "ceptxtCE-USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS-4_2_1_1-3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
    
    Supposed to be wanted like this by removing "txtFrameArr"
    
     [
      {
          "CEPDuplicateTextFrame1": [
            {
              "marked": 1,
              "id_elems": [
                {
                  "PS": "1",
                  "OS": "1",
                  "LS": "999",
                  "name": "MARKETING_CLAIM",
                  "IS": "1",
                  "id": "CE-MARKETING_CLAIM-1_999_1_1"
                }
              ],
              "mapCordinates": [
                {
                  "top": 468.645102009805,
                  "left": 1053.47265625,
                  "width": 30.8357511971699,
                  "height": 132.963461384805
                },
                {
                  "top": 513.29412308266,
                  "left": 1067.05751323149,
                  "width": 91.1260246588899,
                  "height": 233.24627152016
                }
              ],
              "duplicate": 1,
              "content": "baby-dry pants",
              "txtframe_name": "ceptxtduplicateTF1-threaded1"
            }
          ]
        
      },
      {
          "CEPTextFrame2": [
            {
              "marked": 1,
              "id_elems": [
                {
                  "PS": "1",
                  "OS": "1",
                  "LS": "2",
                  "name": "NET_CONTENT_STATEMENT",
                  "IS": "1",
                  "id": "CE-NET_CONTENT_STATEMENT-1_2_1_1"
                }
              ],
              "mapCordinates": [
                {
                  "top": 22.599609375,
                  "left": 740.23886611805,
                  "width": 22.9008135909007,
                  "height": 33.8291015625
                },
                {
                  "top": -6.76171875,
                  "left": 744.522124684196,
                  "width": 15.4768987533043,
                  "height": 9.2734375
                },
                {
                  "top": -14.33203125,
                  "left": 740.448785213874,
                  "width": 22.2500000017299,
                  "height": 6.88811848711339
                }
              ],
              "duplicate": 0,
              "content": "4단계 9-14 kg",
              "txtframe_name": "ceptxtCE-NET_CONTENT_STATEMENT-1_2_1_1-threaded2"
            }
          ]
        
      },
      {
          "CEPTextFrame3": [
            {
              "marked": 1,
              "id_elems": [
                {
                  "PS": "1",
                  "OS": "1",
                  "LS": "2",
                  "name": "USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS",
                  "IS": "4",
                  "id": "CE-USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS-4_2_1_1"
                }
              ],
              "mapCordinates": [
                {
                  "top": 215.9384765625,
                  "left": -639.0234375,
                  "width": 29.1552734375,
                  "height": 55.2314453125
                }
              ],
              "duplicate": 0,
              "content": "위로 당기며 입혀줍니다",
              "txtframe_name": "ceptxtCE-USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS-4_2_1_1-3"
            }
          ]
        
      }
    ]
        Supposed to be wanted like this by removing "txtFrameArr"

I need to remove {"txtFrameArr"} but the key,value needs to be retain
Is there any specific function in Java Spring for this solution?
```

Supposed to be wanted like this by removing "txtFrameArr"

```
Is there any specific function in Java Spring for this solution?
```

Comment: "Remove the key, but retain it". Impossible. If you remove it, then it's not retained. Please clarify, e.g. by showing (in the question) what you expect the result to be, such that the `txtFrameArr` key is both *removed* and *retained* at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If I get correctly what you mean - you could use JSON Path:

1. get all values of your objects *txtFrameArr* key.
2. Create new json array with extracted values:

For first step - you could use com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:*, for second step - either GSON or Jackson

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code will look like this:

```
        List<Map<String, Object>> frames = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$[*].txtFrameArr");
        String newJson = new Gson().toJson(frames);
        System.out.println("object: " + newJson);
```